# Python subprocess : Difficulties in using Pipe and communciate

Tags: python, subprocess

[C Code of binary format3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmijd.png)

[Python Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jKHB.png)

I'm basically trying to run '(./format3 | attackString) | grep searchString' in my python script,
but i can't access the pipe of the format3 process (baby in the code), since it's closed after the communicate call.

And i need the communciate call to supply my attackString to the binary.
I know i could write the stdout of baby into a file and then use that file as stdin for grep, but I feel like there has to be another way to solve this.

Comment: Never post an image of code or even image of anything until it's inevitable. Please read [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Consider using `sh` library as it addresses piping issues with function composition:
https://amoffat.github.io/sh/#piping

It is a very neat library that seems to solely solve you problem.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! This looks promising, but I can't find a way to pipe a string into my binary.

Comment: Won't https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.getoutput be sufficient for your task?

It could have looked this way:
`subprocess.getoutput('echo "Attack" | python format3 | grep "searchPattern"')`